# Splunk not showing all databases from Snowflake

Tags: jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, splunk, splunk-dbconnect

I have successfully made connection between splunk and snowflake and able to get test db data from snowflake to splunk. But Splunk is not showing all the databases from snowflake.

Below is the script which I used in Snowflake to create a new user, role and warehouse.

```
USE ROLE SECURITYADMIN;
CREATE OR REPLACE ROLE first_role;

USE ROLE SYSADMIN;
CREATE OR REPLACE warehouse first_wh
  warehouse_size = 'SMALL' 
  auto_suspend = 5
  auto_resume = true
  initially_suspended = true
  comment = 'SPLUNK ONLY NVIDIA' ;

GRANT USAGE, OPERATE on warehouse first_wh to role first_role;


USE ROLE SECURITYADMIN;
CREATE OR REPLACE USER first_user
   password = 'some password' 
   must_change_password = false
   default_warehouse = first_wh
   default_role = first_role
;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on database NVIDIA_DB to ROLE first_role;
GRANT ROLE first_role TO USER first_user;
```

As you can see from the above script that I have created a user (first_user), role (first_role) and a warehouse (first_wh) and have provides ALL privledges.

At splunk I have configured the identities and connections as below.

[Splunk Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TznGi.png)
[Splunk Identity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3L6Yo.png)

But when I go to splunk db connect Input to fetch data it doesnt show me the NVIDIA_DB. Here is the screenshot. Any idea how to resolve it or what I am doing wrong here? Thanks

[Splunk Input Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F4un.png)

Comment: did you populate the jdbc url?

Comment: Are you able to login with that first_user via Snowflake UI and see the NVIDIA_DB?

Comment: Yes I have. Please see the attached image. @Sergiu Yes I can.

Comment: In the Splunk Connection image the jdbc url is showing that the DB is set CHECK1. If you set a DB in a connection then that is the only DB you will be able to access - is this the issue?

Comment: @NickW  Cant even see the CHECK1 db.

Comment: @NickW I dont think thats the issue, cause even after specifying CHECK1 db in url I am able to see some others DBs as well.

Comment: I am not seeing any screenshot with login via Snowflake UI, not Splunk. So, are you able to login with a browser to Snowflake UI and see that database using user first_user @FaisalGhufran?

Comment: @Sergiu Just checked I am not able to see the NVIDIA_DB with user first_user. But in the above script I gave privileges to first_user to access this db. Can you please look whats wrong in script

Comment: Hi - I have just run your scripts and when I then log into Snowflake using first_user I can see/access the NVIDIA DB. I suggest you re-run your scripts and see if that makes a difference. If it doesn't, please provide the output from running: SHOW GRANTS TO ROLE first_role;

Comment: @NickW Great you are helping. here is the result of the query which you asked me to run. https://ibb.co/Zz46W5T

Comment: That's showing the user has access to the CHECK1 DB, not the NVIDIA DB. Try running this again: USE ROLE SECURITYADMIN; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on database NVIDIA_DB to ROLE first_role; Once that has run, run SHOW GRANTS TO ROLE first_role; again and see if that's now showing the user has access to the NVIDIA DB

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what was wrong, you have to specifically give rights to each table that you want to access from splunk. go to snowflake > databases > desired table > click on the table > on the right side there is windows which shows grant option > click there and grant rights to this tables.